# How to make a recursive ListView in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, recursion

My model looks like

```
public class MyVm 
{
    public string MyTitle { get; set; }
    public List<MyVm> Children { get; set; }

    public MyVm()
    {
        this.Children = new List<MyVm>();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to list through all the `children` and `children`'s `children`, which I *think* is recursive.

The MainWindow code behind is

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.Kids = new List<MyVm>();
        var m = new MyVm();
        m.MyTitle = "Title1";
        var m2 = new MyVm();
        m2.MyTitle = "Title2";
        var m3 = new MyVm();
        m3.MyTitle = "Title3";
        var m4 = new MyVm();
        m4.MyTitle = "Title4";

        m.Children.Add(m2);
        m2.Children.Add(m3);
        m3.Children.Add(m4);
        this.Kids.Add(m);
    }

    public List<MyVm> Kids { get; set; }
```

and finally the MainWIndow view is

```
     <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTitle}" />
                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" ItemContainerStyle="{Binding MyStyle}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Kids}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}" />
```

As you can see I've tried to re-use the same resource for each 'children' to achieve the recursive bit, but sadly, the only thing I see rendered is a single `TextBlock` with `Title2`

Comment: It's only recursive if one of the children contains an element in the ancestor line. Otherwise it's just hierarchical.

Comment: @H.B.... Yes, I think I understand that but I don't believe my data is recursive (as you point out), but I'm trying to be recursive in the XAML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it

```
   <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type a:MyVm}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTitle}" />
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding }" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Kids}"  />
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know that implicit templates could get around the cyclical reference problem.

Answer (score 1):

For these purposes you would use a [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) (which has its own `ItemsSource` property that you would bind to `Children`), i am not sure if a `ListBox` supports it. If not use a `TreeView` and change the control templates to remove the indentation and the collapse toggle button if you don't want that.

Comment: Exactly the same thing occurs... It shows me just 1 item... (I updated to TreeView)

Comment: The `HierarchicalDataTemplate` content should only be the representation of a single item, do not nest additional `ListBoxes` in there or the like. The parent control has to take care of that, that's the whole point, otherwise you will be stuck at the next level because you cannot reference the template inside itself. And yes, i did not expect the `ListBox` to handle that.

Comment: I can't get this to format, but is this what you meant (if you can read it :( )? `<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem"><Setter Property="ItemTemplate"><Setter.Value><HierarchicalDataTemplate>                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTitle}" />                            </StackPanel>                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>                    </Setter.Value>                </Setter>` As this is still not working...

Comment: You didn't bind `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource`.

Comment: I'm obviously messing this up big time... `<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">                 <Setter Property="ItemTemplate"><Setter.Value><HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type a:MyVm}">
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTitle}" /></HierarchicalDataTemplate></Setter.Value></Setter>
            </Style>` But I think I'm getting the concept... The HierrarchicalDataTemplate will look into all the child elemens of the bound element, and if we use a DataTemplate, we can express which properties we're binding too

Comment: Oh yeah, if you set the `x:Key` of the `Style` it will not be applied implicitly, wouldn't do that.